# What's wrong in this simple MySQL SELECT query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

The select:

```
   SELECT pr.predmet            AS naziv_predmeta, 
           pr.protustranka_naziv AS protustranka 
    WHERE  pr.datetime > Date_add (Now(), INTERVAL 24 hour)
```

I keep getting

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE pr.datetime > Date_add (Now(), INTERVAL 24 hour)' at line > 3

Table structure:

```
protustranka_naziv varchar(255)
predmet varchar(255)
datetime datetime
```

EDIT: Ok, so the first step was to add the FROM clause /facepalm. But the problem is, I still keep getting an error message. This is the query:

```
SELECT pr.predmet AS naziv_predmeta, pr.protustranka_naziv AS protustranka
FROM ou_predmeti
WHERE pr.datetime > DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 24 HOUR ) 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

This is the message:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') LIMIT 0, 30' at line 4

EDIT2: I missed again, it should have been `FROM ou_predmeti pr`

Comment: I'm an idiot, sometimes you don't see the tree from the forest, tnx guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot your `FROM` clause

```
SELECT pr.predmet AS naziv_predmeta, 
       pr.protustranka_naziv AS protustranka 
FROM ????
WHERE  pr.datetime > Date_add (Now(), INTERVAL 24 hour)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the vital `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT pr.predmet            AS naziv_predmeta, 
       pr.protustranka_naziv AS protustranka 
FROM <TABLE-NAME-HERE> AS pr
WHERE  pr.datetime > Date_add (Now(), INTERVAL 24 hour)
```

Answer (score 1):

you missing `FROM` clause

```
SELECT pr.predmet            AS naziv_predmeta, 
       pr.protustranka_naziv AS protustranka 
FROM your_table              AS pr
WHERE  pr.datetime > Date_add (Now(), INTERVAL 24 hour)
```